# Sync database from Firebase to Supabase

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, supabase, flutter-windows

**Context:**
I created an app for Android users a long time ago. Thats a simple app for customers ask for food. This app uses Firebase Realtime Database to send the orders to the server. The structure of database is quite simple, with just some nodes/tables.
The main point is that the server system was made with C# and Windows Forms, and actually is outdated and I don't want to spend more time updating it. For some reasons, now I'm migrating this old C# system to Flutter. Coded everything and will build a Flutter Desktop Application.
But unfortunately, I did not checked the Firebase Realtime Database compatibility with Windows, and now, in the end of project, was surprised by this. Firebase Realtime Database is not available for Flutter Desktop.

**Idea:**
After some searches, decided to try the Supabase Database, that will do the trick for what I need, and have full support to Flutter for Windows Apps.

**Problem:**
Actually, the customers still are using the Android App to send orders to the restaurant and I'm stucked to Firebase. I think change the Android App to Supabase is not an option, because I want to migrate this app to Flutter Web soon.

**Question:**
So, the best situation would be get all changes and data from Firebase to Supabase,
and I haven't figured out how to do that. Is there a way to sync data from Firebase to Supabase without constructing an application?

PS: if anyone has suggestions to get the data in another way or resolve the Windows x Firebase incompatibility issue, would be appreciated.

Comment: You could setup Firebase cloud function to listen to database changes on your realtime database, and update the Supabase database from within the cloud function. On your desktop application, you can use Supabase realtime to listen to realtime changes to update the information in realtime.

Comment: @dshukertjr thanks so much. I really think there is a way to make this work with cloud functions. I will give a try. I will keep the question open for more sugestions and to show how I will solve it, because I believe this subject can help others in the future and dont have much infos about.